# How do I hide bulk operations form for a specified user role?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view where I list user's own contents, this contains bulk operations. Users with "add article" permission can see this bulk operations thing but I would like to hide this bulk operations "form element" / "functions" for users in employee role.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: did you try going to `/admin/people/permissions` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I cannot hide bulk operations "elements" there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the bulk operations "form element" use ViewExecutable->removeHandler in hook_views_pre_view():

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function rgr_main_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {

  if ($view->id() === 'content') {
    $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $is_employee = in_array('employee', $account->getRoles());

    if ($is_employee) {
      $view->removeHandler($view->current_display, 'field', 'node_bulk_form');
    }
  }
}
```

This will hide the dropdown form elements, the checkbox in the row and the submit buttons.

Comment: This works as expected, but note that it requires `use \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;` or you're going to get an error like `Argument 1 passed to hook_views_pre_view() must be an instance of ViewExecutable` - and this function also takes more than one parameter. See [hook_views_pre_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/8.6.x)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the appropriate permissions for the employee role.

What you need to look for is not views bulk operations permission, or similar, what you really need is to uncheck the permissions related to nodes.

So if you uncheck the permissions for adding, editing and deleting content, then those bulk operations should be gone as well.